# Routing requests through controllers in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm fairly new to MVC and I hope someone can spare some time to point me in the right direction. I was given a school assignment to create a simple wiki page where a user can search for and create articles. So I have a main index page where I have a zone for the menu, another one for the table of contents, a welcome message, and a search box for an article.

One important directive I have is to implement my own routing (without modifying the `RouteConfig.cs` file). Each of the following requests must call the right action method in my controller:

```
/ or /home or home/index: displays the welcome page;

home/index/<title of article>: displays the article;

home/index/<inexisting title>: invitation to create the article;

home/modify/title: modify the article;

home/add/title: add an article;

home/delete/title: delete the article.
```

For now, I have a basic `HomeController` with an `ActionResult Index()` method that returns the index view, but I am a bit stumped as to how to properly get started and the next methods I should be creating to respond to these requests, most notably, how I go about passing on the specified parameters to these controller methods.

I would appreciate any advice to kick start things.

-Jeff

Comment: Welcome to SO. First start by showing what you have done so far as a [mcve]

Comment: What does it mean when you say you "have to implement your own routing?"  Does that mean you have to customize the routing behavior or just ensure that the routes you quoted work?  If you structure your controllers and actions correctly, the routes specified would work using the "default" route rules that are typically in `RouteConfig`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think my main challenge is structuring my controllers and actions correctly. Mainly, I don't understand the difference, in terms of the action method's signature, between home/index/<article title> and something like home/modify/title as specified by the teacher in terms of how parameters are passed. To me, both will require an ActionResult method that receives the article title as a paramameter, so the first one would be ActionResult Index(string article_title) and the second one would be ActionResult Modify (string article_title). Am I right in assuming this?

Comment: Using the default routes, yes.  But you likely will need to make the signature of your action methods `Modify(string id)` because the default routes in MVC will try to map the part after the action name to a field called `id` and unless you are permitted to modify route rules (can you use attribute routing?) then it won't map correctly to `article_title`

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the answer Stephen, it clarifies things.